# MCMC - Is Gelman-Rubin diagnostic criteria good for checking convergence of MCMC chains sampling from multimodal distribution?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am using Bayesian inference to estimate some parameter in a model. 
My parameter space is multimodel - most likely bimodal. 
Is the Gelman-Rubin diagnostic criteria a good way to check convergence?

It gives a false impression of convergence when it's value is below 1.2, however if I continue the runs, it goes back up.

Below are the trace plots of three parameters and trend in the GR statistics. 
I am using DREAM MCMC algorithm.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Similar behavior has been noticed before. Please refer to our paper preprint [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09384) and R package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stableGR/index.html).